# Coldfusion 11 - Global variables - Application.cfc or Application.cfm

Tags: variables, coldfusion, global-variables, coldfusion-11

I'm working on an application done in Coldfusion 9. I have to migrate it in CF11 and I would like to improve the code.  The current application in CF9 is done like this:

**Application.cfm**:

```
<cfapplication  name="MyApp"
            clientManagement="yes"
            clientStorage="registry"
            setClientCookies="yes"
            sessionManagement="yes"
            sessionTimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,1,0,0)#"
            applicationTimeout="#CreateTimeSpan(0,0,2,0)#" 
/>  

<cfset application.datasource   = "MyApp"/>
<cfset application.name         = "MyApp"/>
<cfset application.access       = "App"/>
<cfset application.version      = "1.1"/>
<cfset application.title        = "My Application"/>

<cfset application.inc_path     = "includes"/>
<cfset application.com_path     = "components"/>
<cfset application.scripts_path = "scripts"/>
<cfset application.styles_path      = "styles"/>

<cfset application.email = "firstname.lastnane@myapplication.com" />
<cfset application.YEAR  = 2016/>

<cfif Not IsDefined("session.language_cd")>
    <cfset session.language_cd = "ENG">
</cfif>

<cfset session.email_support_team = "support@myapplication.com" />

<cfinclude template="ui_lib.cfm">
```

Inside the file "**ui_lib.cfm**", there are a lot of variables defined and used in all other .cfm files:

```
<cfswitch expression="#session.ui_lng_cd#">  
    <cfcase value="FRA">
        <cfset ui_lib_abbrev                    = "Abbr&eacute;viation" />
        <cfset ui_lib_acces                     = "Acc&egrave;s" />
        <cfset ui_lib_active_sans_accent        = "Actif" />
   </cfcase>
    <cfcase value="ENG">
        <cfset ui_lib_abbrev                    = "Abbreviation" />
        <cfset ui_lib_acces                     = "Access" />
        <cfset ui_lib_active_sans_accent        = "Active" />
  </cfcase>
</cfswitch>
```

For example in **menu.cfm**:

```
<div id="menu">
    <h5><cfoutput>#session.user#</cfoutput></h5>
    <ul>
    <li><cfoutput>#ui_lib_abbrev#</cfoutput></li>
    <li><cfoutput>#ui_lib_acces#</cfoutput></li>
    <li><cfoutput>#ui_lib_active_sans_accent#</cfoutput></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to create an **Application.cfc** to replace **application.cfm**:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="MyApp">
    <cfset This.name = "MyApp">

    <cfset This.sessionManagement="yes">
    <cfset This.clientManagement="no">
    <cfset This.loginStorage="session">
    <cfset This.sessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,0,1)>
    <cfset This.applicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan(0,0,2,0) >
    <cfset This.setClientCookies="no">
    <cfset This.domainCookies="yes">
    <cfset This.scriptProtect = "All">

    <cffunction name="onApplicationStart">        

        <cfscript>
            Application.homePage    = "/index.cfm";
            Application.datasource  = "MyApp";
            Application.name            = "MyApp";
            Application.access      = "App";
            Application.version         = "1.1";
            Application.title       = "My Application";

            Application.inc_path        = "includes";
            Application.com_path        = "components";
            Application.scripts_path    = "scripts";
            Application.styles_path     = "styles";
            Application.email = "firstname.lastnane@myapplication.com"
            Application.YEAR  = 2016;          

        </cfscript>

        <cfinclude template="ui_lib.cfm">

    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="onSessionStart">
         <cfif Not IsDefined("session.language_cd")>
              <cfset session.language_cd = "ENG">
         </cfif>

        <cfif Not IsDefined("session.g_exercice")>
            <cfset todayDate = Now()>
            <cfset SESSION.g_exercice = #DateFormat(todayDate, "yyyy")#>
        </cfif>          

        <cfif Not IsDefined("session.sec_first_pass")>
            <cfset SESSION.sec_first_pass = 0>
        </cfif> 

        <cfset session.email_support_team = "support@myapplication.com" />

    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

1. I have created application.cfc and removed application.cfm and tried to run the application. It's ok, but I have Coldfusion errors with the variables defined in ui_lib.cfm. The server says that the variables are not defined. Could you please tell me why and how to solve the problem?
2. I would like to know if it's better to use a file Application.cfc with the same definitions or keep the current file Application.cfm ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *errors with the variables defined in ui_lib.cfm* That is because unlike with an Application.cfm, the `onApplicationStart` *method* does not execute on every request. As the name implies, it only executes once - when the application starts. Take a look at the `OnRequestStart` and/or `OnRequest` methods. *if it's better...* Best is relative, but Application.cfc is generally preferred as they have more functionality than the (older) Application.cfm.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to include the template in the function OnRequestStart or OnRequest function. But the problem is still the same. Could you tell me please if have to put all variables in application? for example change <cfset ui_lib_abbrev = "Abbreviation" /> in <cfset application.ui_lib_abbrev = "Abbreviation" /> ? Apparently it's working now but I don't know if it's the best way.

Comment: You can use the application scope. However, it is not required. The include should work with OnRequest. Can you post the code you used?

Comment: onRequestStart is the function I would use.  If it's giving you bad results, look at where the undefined variable should have been defined.  Also, if you suspect the include file is not being included, output some static text at the very start of it to verify your suspicions.

Comment: BTW, I agree with Adrian that the [application scope is probably more appropriate in the scenario](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38834081/104223). Just wanted to point out that you *can* use the variables scope in combination with onRequest/Start. If it is not working, it is likely due to a code/syntax error in your Application.cfc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some cfm to cfc conversions and the answer depends upon the usage. As has been mentioned, session based logic in the application scope won't work.

If there's a way to change the user's language which updates the session.ui_lng_cd value and therefore the language displayed to the user then the easiest answer is to set language variables in the OnRequestStart event. You'll have to change the scope of the variables to the **request** scope when set and used but hopefully that'll be easy enough with a global search and replace.

*Additional notes:*

It would also be possible to store those language variables in the session, by placing the code in the OnSessionStart event but generally it's a good idea to keep session storage minimal as if you start storing a lot in session on a busy site it can use up a lot of memory.

Another way to do this that would take more work but I think is more efficient if you have a lot of these would be to create a two level array in the application that stores the language strings and use the session language as the first level of key. This way very little memory is used on each request to old variables.

So in your application.cfc OnApplicationStart you'd have:

```
application.languageStrings = {};
application.languageStrings["ENG"] = {};
application.languageStrings["ENG"]["ui_lib_abbrev"] = "Abbreviation";
application.languageStrings["ENG"]["ui_lib_acces"] = "Access";
application.languageStrings["ENG"]["ui_lib_active_sans_accent"] = "Active";
application.languageStrings["FRA"] = {};
application.languageStrings["FRA"]["ui_lib_abbrev"] = "Abbr&eacute;viatio";
application.languageStrings["FRA"]["ui_lib_acces"] = "Acc&egrave;s";
application.languageStrings["FRA"]["ui_lib_active_sans_accent"] = "Actif";
```

And to output the right string you'd use:

```
#application.languageStrings[session.language_cd]["ui_lib_active_sans_accent"]#
```

Answer (score 1):

The variables defined in your UDF are places in the `variables` scope, but by placing the UDF inside `onApplicationStart()`, the include happens only the one time instead of every request. I think you've figured that out and have them defined again in the `variables` scope.

I feel the more appropriate solution would be to place them into the `application` scope so they're just defined the one time instead of them being redefined on every request.

```
application.ui = {
    "ENG" = {
        "abbrev" = "Abbreviation"
        , "acces" = "Access"
        , "active_sans_accent" = "Active"
    }
    , "FRA" = {
        "abbrev" = "Abbréviation"
        , "acces" = "Accès"
        , "active_sans_accent" = "Actif"
    }
};
```

Then just update any existing reference like so: `#application.ui[session.ui_lng_cd].abbrev#`.

If your need to manage translated context grows in the future, take a look at [Resource Bundles](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/concept.html).

Comment: If the variables are put into the application scope, then he would have to edit every place a variable is used to add `application.`.

Comment: That's why I said "then just update any existing reference". :) It's up to OP to determine the ROI.